# drupal 8.1 blocks config choices different from D8

Tags: 8, blocks

I did a migration in Nov/2015 of my D6 to D8 and the blocks look like this.

> [image: screenshot]

Then I repeated the migration of my D6 to D8 on May/2016 and my blocks 
look like this.

> [image: screenshot]

They are different.

Where is the documentation for the configuration of the block visibility

Thanks,

Comment: It seems you have more modules installed, in the second screenshot. Are the blocks created in the same way?

Comment: The second screen shots does not have more blocks.  The second migration was created by downloading drupal8.1.0 and then I added all of the modules from my first migration then I did a migration from D6 to D8 and all of a sudden I get all the extra choices in the block.  This morning

Comment: This morning I did a different approach to update my migration from D8.0 to D8.1.  I copied all of files from D8.1 into my migrated D8.0 and after restarting the migrated site running D8.1 I also can see all of these extra choices.  Somehow all of these extra choices show up but I can not find documentation about it or why they are are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a difference between 8.0 and 8.1, it happens in both versions.

It is a core bug, triggered by ctools. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2632434

Comment: Berdir - Thanks the info.  Is good to know that it is not something I did :-)